Mbed OS Studio Debugger (pyOCD) errors out writing wrong firmware address
I am getting the error :WARNING:builder:Chip erase used when flash address 0x8020000 is not the same as flash start 0x8000000 when trying to load a debug target on a STM32H743VITx device. Which is overwriting the bootloader and crashing the firmware during a debug session.
. I have the set the correct mbed_rom_start in custom_target json and building and loading the Release builds does flash correctly but it is crashing somewhere after that. Which is why i am trying to run the on device debugger. The problem is that the pyocd flash erase is using 0x80000 as flash address and not 0x8020000.
"bootloader_supported": true,
"mbed_rom_start": "0x8020000",
"mbed_ram_size":  "0x100000",
"mbed_size":      "0x200000",
"mbed_ram_start": "0x20000000",

Is there anyway to configure the debug target to use the correct address? Am I doing something else wrong? I tried adding base-address to the debug flags but errors starting the server.
--target STM32H743VITx   --erase=chip --frequency 1800000 --pack '/Library/Application Support/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/cmsis-packs/Keil.STM32H7xx_DFP.2.7.0-small.pack' -O connect_mode=under-reset

I also tried updating STM32H743VITx target in ./mbed-os/tools/arm_pack_manager/index.json with
    "algorithms": [
        {
            "default": true,
            "file_name": "CMSIS/Flash/STM32H7x_2048.FLM",
            "ram_size": 1048576,
            "ram_start": 536870912,
            "size": 2097152,
            "start": 134348800
        }

==================
Selected port 50000 for debugging
0000452:INFO:board:Target type is stm32h743vitx
0000527:INFO:coresight_target:Asserting reset prior to connect
0000585:INFO:dap:DP IDR = 0x6ba02477 (v2 rev6)
0000639:INFO:ap:AHB-AP#0 IDR = 0x84770001 (AHB-AP var0 rev8)
0000641:INFO:ap:AHB-AP#1 IDR = 0x84770001 (AHB-AP var0 rev8)
0000643:INFO:ap:APB-AP#2 IDR = 0x54770002 (APB-AP var0 rev5)
0000648:INFO:rom_table:AHB-AP#0 Class 0x1 ROM table #0 @ 0xe00fe000 (designer=020 part=483)
0000650:INFO:rom_table:[0]
0000650:INFO:rom_table:  AHB-AP#0 Class 0x1 ROM table #1 @ 0xe00ff000 (designer=43b part=4c7)
0000652:INFO:rom_table:  [0]
0000653:INFO:rom_table:  [1]
0000654:INFO:rom_table:  [2]
0000655:INFO:rom_table:  [3]
0000656:INFO:rom_table:[1]
0000657:INFO:rom_table:[2]
0000658:INFO:rom_table:APB-AP#2 Class 0x1 ROM table #0 @ 0xe00e0000 (designer=020 part=483)
0000660:INFO:rom_table:[0]
0000661:WARNING:rom_table:Invalid coresight component, cidr=0x0
0000661:INFO:rom_table:[2]
0000662:ERROR:rom_table:Error attempting to probe CoreSight component referenced by ROM table entry #5: Memory transfer fault (read) @ 0xe00f0fbc-0xe00f1043
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Application Support/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyocd/coresight/rom_table.py", line 358, in _read_table
    self._handle_table_entry(entry, entryNumber)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyocd/coresight/rom_table.py", line 408, in _handle_table_entry
    cmpid.read_id_registers()
  File "/Library/Application Support/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyocd/coresight/rom_table.py", line 113, in read_id_registers
    regs = self.ap.read_memory_block32(self.top_address + self.IDR_READ_START, self.IDR_READ_COUNT)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyocd/probe/stlink_probe.py", line 271, in read_memory_block32
    return self._read_mem(addr, size, Commands.JTAG_READMEM_32BIT, self.MAXIMUM_TRANSFER_SIZE, apsel)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyocd/probe/stlink/stlink.py", line 343, in _read_mem
    raise exc
pyocd.core.exceptions.TransferFaultError: Memory transfer fault (read) @ 0xe00f0fbc-0xe00f1043
0000664:INFO:cortex_m:CPU core #0 is Cortex-M7 r1p2
0000666:INFO:cortex_m:FPU present: FPv5-D16-M
0000668:INFO:dwt:4 hardware watchpoints
0000671:INFO:fpb:8 hardware breakpoints, 1 literal comparators
0000678:INFO:coresight_target:Deasserting reset post connect
0000683:INFO:server:Semihost server started on port 4444 (core 0)
0000693:INFO:gdbserver:GDB server started on port 50000 (core 0)
Reading symbols from /Users/seanmccully/Sources/CNC/Remora/Firmware/FirmwareSource/Remora-OS6/BUILD/SKRV3/ARMC6/firmware_application.elf...
warning: 
Loadable section "RW_IRAM1" outside of ELF segments
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
0000803:INFO:gdbserver:Client connected to port 50000!
warning: Loadable section "RW_IRAM1" outside of ELF segments
0x080002c2 in ?? ()
0000896:INFO:gdbserver:Attempting to load argon
0000896:INFO:gdbserver:Attempting to load freertos
0000896:INFO:gdbserver:Attempting to load rtx5
0000896:INFO:gdbserver:Attempting to load threadx
0000896:INFO:gdbserver:Attempting to load zephyr
Resetting target with halt
Successfully halted device on reset
Attached to debugger on port 50000
0001539:WARNING:builder:Chip erase used when flash address 0x8020000 is not the same as flash start 0x8000000
0018000:INFO:loader:Erased chip, programmed 201728 bytes (197 pages), skipped 60416 bytes (59 pages) at 15.00 kB/s
Resetting target with halt
Successfully halted device on reset
Image loaded: /Users/seanmccully/Sources/CNC/Remora/Firmware/FirmwareSource/Remora-OS6/BUILD/SKRV3/ARMC6/firmware_application.elf
Note: automatically using hardware breakpoints for read-only addresses.
Program
 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xfffffffe in ?? ()
0036510:INFO:gdbserver:Client detached
0036510:INFO:gdbserver:Client disconnected from port 50000!


This is documented on the MBED Site for devices with a bootloader need to use erase=sector instead of chip.
